# Tweenjs randomized values in repeating tween

Tags: tweenjs

Exploring Tweenjs. I just want to move some circles randomly around the stage. I understand that all tweening is "deterministic," meaning that it uses pre-calculated values for speed. So I have two functions that call each other. The 2nd function is called when the tween completes. Unfortunately, I'm getting a call stack overflow error.

HOw can i make this run forever and move circles endlessly to random positions?

```
function tweenPosition(circle) {
    var xPosition = Math.random() * stageWidth
    var yPosition = Math.random() * stageHeight

    createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop: false}).wait(0).to({x: xPosition, y: yPosition}, 1000, createjs.Ease.sineInOut).onComplete(tweenPositionComplete(this, xPosition, yPosition))
}
function tweenPositionComplete(circle, x, y) {
    circle.x = x
    circle.y = y
    tweenPosition(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Tween instance inside the `tweenPosition` function, instead of using the `onComplete` method, use the `call` method, and add it at the end of that Tween instance.

```
call (callback, [params], [scope])
```

In the case of your code:

```
.call(tweenPositionComplete, [circle, xPosition, yPosition])
```

Your Tween will look like this:

```
createjs.Tween
        .get(circle, {loop:false})
        .wait(0)
        .to({x:xPosition, y:yPosition}, 1000, createjs.Ease.sineInOut)
        .call(tweenPositionComplete, [circle, xPosition, yPosition]);
```

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrisMVP3200/f7vo5gu6/) you can see it in action.

**See also**: [Tween Class (TweenJS API)](http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the nice answer!